# How to display has_many items in the belongs to show view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a student and sublet post in my database.
So sublet post belongs to Student.

Student Model

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sublet_posts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Sublet Post Model

```
class SubletPost < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student

end
```

Route

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :sublet_posts
  resources :students
end
```

Student Controller

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_student, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /students
  # GET /students.json
  def index
    @students = Student.all
  end

  # GET /students/1
  # GET /students/1.json
  def show
    # student_id should be the current user id 
    @sublet_posts = SubletPost.where(student_id:1)
  end

  # GET /students/new
  def new
    @student = Student.new
  end

  # GET /students/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /students
  # POST /students.json
  def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.save
        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /students/1
  # PATCH/PUT /students/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student.update(student_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @student, notice: 'Student was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @student }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @student.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /students/1
  # DELETE /students/1.json
  def destroy
    @student.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to students_url, notice: 'Student was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_student
      @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def student_params
      params.require(:student).permit(:fname, :lname, :email, :password, :phone, :dob)
    end
end
```

Student show view

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div>
  <h3>Sublet Post</h3>
    <%= link_to "New Sublet Post", new_sublet_post_path %>
  <% @sublet_posts.each do |sublet_post| %>
    <%= sublet_post.created_at %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_sublet_post_path(sublet_post.id) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In the student controller, I have @sublet_posts = SubletPost.where(student_id:1), but I hard coded student_id:1, so every post created is in the student id: 1. Is there a way to display the sublet posts to the student that it belongs to?

Also, in the _form in the sublet post

```
<%= form_with(model: sublet_post, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if sublet_post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(sublet_post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this sublet_post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% sublet_post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= form.hidden_field :student_id, :value => '1' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>


<% end %>
```

I assigned the hidden value to 1, but is there a way to assign it to the student.id that belongs to?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: When you say "I assigned the hidden value to 1, but is there a way to assign it to the student.id that belongs to?", this depends on how your application works, would you want to choose from a list of students to select the right id, or is the current logged in user the one that should be assigned to the sublet for instance?

Comment: Instead of `@sublet_posts = SubletPost.where(student_id:1)`, you could get all sublet_posts by `@sublet_posts = @student.sublet_posts`.

Also is the form for sublet post separate or together with student form?

Comment: @PrabinPoudel Thank you and They are separated.

Comment: @the-undefined Thank you and I would like to assign the id to the current logged in.

Answer (score 2):

You should do the following:(you got `before_action` to pull the student, just use it.)

```
def show
  @sublet_posts = @student.sublet_posts if @student.present?
end
```

in your view just iterate the `@sublet_posts`:

```
<% @sublet_posts.each do |sb| %>
  <%= sb.created_at %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_sublet_post_path(sb.id) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't think this will require @student.present? since if record with id is not found it will throw error while setting student.